# How to implement deployment freeze in kubernetes infrastructure?

Tags: kubernetes, microservices

Any big project is subject of code freeze in special moments of the year, mine included. In our context, we work with microservices architecture, where each team is responsable for the entire cycle coding->deploying, where deployment means changing a k8s deployment.yaml file that points to a new docker image with the latest changes.

However, the way we deal with freezes is that we simply don't merge any changes into the deployment.yaml of any of our services, this way, k8s won't deploy anything new. But IMO this approach is not ideal and easily bypassed because there isn't any real blocker, it's just a common agreement that we won't merge such PRs so that we don't change the deployment.yaml.

This way, my question would be if there is a known way, be that in kubernetes configurations or somewhere else, where I can enforce a real freeze and be 100% sure that nothing will be deployed in the meantime?

Even better if I were allowed to keep merging changes in deployment.yaml of my services, but only have the changes actually deployed upon freezing end.

-> In case you also don't know any existing way to do it, please leave your suggestions on how you think this could be done because Im heading to my final project in college and I think this could be an interesting topic...

Comment: If you are using a ci/cd workflow (e.g., using [ArgoCD](https://argo-cd.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)), you can pin your configuration to a particular commit in your repository. Updates only happen via code review and passing your ci/cd pipeline, so you don't get any surprise updates. By limiting who can approve the pull requests you control who can trigger new deployments.

Comment: Most of the deployments for this workflow should trigger via PR merges to repos, so as long as the person who is opening the PR does not have an approval he wont be able to merge anything and hence no deployments.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question will vary according to some parameters, but there are generally 2 main access points that can change production which should be controlled in order to achieve a hermetic code freeze -

1. CI/CD pipelines - This is the most common way to deploy changes to production these days. In my previous company, when we wanted to prevent developers from deploying changes during a code freeze, we would delete production credentials from the CI/CD system during the code freeze, and that way no change can be deployed even if it is merged to master.
   As @larsks mentioned in the comments - if you are using GitOps, you might have to pin the current change to a specific commit/tag in git.
2. Manual changes - If developers in the organization have access to change production manually, you will have to address this as well. You can either block manual access until the end of the code freeze, or make sure the policy is clearly communicated to everyone with production access (since manual changes don't are less probable to happen unintentionally)

Another point to address when implementing code freeze is out of band access to apply hotfixes and other urgent changes. When cutting access to production there should still be an emergency route allowing changes to production to be applied, and it should be simple and quick - because it will often be applied in times of stress and downtime.